# Updating the input text value based on user input and display the value

Tags: javascript, input

I want to get the user input in an input field and then display a return message on click. Code is like this:

```
var link = document.getElementById("link");
var getNames = document.getElementById("getName");
var lastName = getNames.value;

function showName (lastName) {
var nameIntro = "Your name is ";

function makeFullName () {       
return nameIntro  + " " + lastName;   
}

return makeFullName ();
}
link.addEventListener('click',function(){link.innerHTML+=showName     (lastName);
});
```

I can get this to work without this closure, but only for a given name. I want to pass the user input as argument, and this does not work.

I have checked answers, but i could not find a native JS example where the issue at hand was the same.

link to pen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/RRWzdr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `getNames.value` to your function:

```
link.addEventListener('click', function(){
    link.innerHTML += showName(getNames.value);
});
```

This is because you set `lastName` at a moment when the user has not yet input anything.

#### Remark

Using `innerHTML` is not advised, as it may go wrong when the input name has `<` or `&`, however unlikely that may be. Also adding to HTML with `+=` is not advised.

Instead reserve a `span` to contain only the name:

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.facebook.com">
  <img src="http://www.bzeaz.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/img-thing.jpg" width=100 height=100>
  <span id="name"></span>
</a>
```

And in JavaScript use `textContent`:

```
var setName = document.getElementById("name");
// ...
link.addEventListener('click',function(){
    setName.textContent = showName(getNames.value);
});
```

Comment: Just a side note: `innerHTML +=` is bad habit because it causes the browser to reparse all of the HTML in that element. Prefer [`link.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', showName(getNames.value));`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: Thank you guys, this seemed trivial, because it did not throw any error or undefined. Lesson learned here.